# Visual studio 2010 removes code on debugging

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am having a strange problem in Visual Studio; the problem is that when I write a css line like this:

```
.Wrapper
{
    width:1050px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:1000px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

and press the debug button, Visual Studio removes the last line of the code something like below example:

```
.Wrapper
{
    width:1050px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:1000px;
    pad
}
```

However it is not just css it happen all over, and it happen sometime not always.

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "visual studio remove the last line?"  Does it disappear from the editor?  Is it no longer in the file - what if you open in a different editor?  If this happens in every file, does that mean that none of your pages are displaying correctly in the browser?

Comment: well it just simply removes the last code I have write some time all of it and sometime part of it like above example, how ever when I stop the debugging and press ctrl+z it will put back the removed line. if i press save button before debugging it will not removes the line. usually i have this problem on css file, but sometime its happened on .cs and html code as well.

Comment: So, when you have the problem on the css file, does the change take effect in the debugged application?  Given the example you stated above, does your `.Wrapper` element display incorrectly?

Comment: quickfix: save before debugging

Comment: yes it will effects the .Wrapper and display it incorrectly, i remember i have had same problem before in the home as well and i have found a fix installer and overcome the problem, but i cant remember where i have download it, i hope someone knows where it is. and give me the link.